# MOSS2007 error 500

Tags: sharepoint

We have a MOSS 2007 install that has been very stable for years. A few days ago it started not allowing people to upload files to documents and tickets. Today I ran os updates and now we are getting some errors, first it pointed me to a ms KB fix so i did that which ran updates, all worked except for one and now the system is throwing a 500 error. I checked the server logs and seem to be getting some odd errors for several days now which i think points to a bigger issue.

Looking for anyone that can help me get back up and running quickly, for pay of course.

Thanks

Comment: Seriously, if you want to pay anyone, call Microsoft and pay them $260. They will work with you until it is fixed for one price, and who knows the product better than them? : (800) 936-4900

Comment: Can you add the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Sync the sharepoint service account password. Check the IIS and see if the site is started or not. Clear the cachi.ini of sharepoint servers. 
check this and it might help. http://www.ekhichdi.com/e/How-to-clear-cache.ini-file-346.html